# Passing variable sized 2D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

If I have a function, say, as follows:

```
int fun(int n,int a[n][n]){......}
```

Where n is some value I get from the user via standard input runtime. Am I allowed to use the `n` in `[]` for defining `a[n][n]`?

This seems to work in C but not in C++. What is an alternative if I want the exact same functionality in C++?(i.e. take an input as parameter, and the 2D array size itself should be dependent on this parameter)

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable sized arrays. [I recommend using `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). To get a 2D-like `vector`, [do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Comment: It is allowed in C99 only (and, from memory, deprecated and removed from subsequent C standards).   It has never been allowed in C++.   In C++, use a standard container (say, `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`) which has the advantage that the container itself has information about its own number of elements (i.e. `n` doesn't need to be passed separately).

Comment: Son of a gun. I knew C99 added VLA, but I didn't know you could pass the array size in along with the array. Neat.

Comment: VLAs weren't removed from C11, but they were made optional. From what I gather, this is partly because few compilers actually bothered to implement them from C99.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Raw C arrays are generally not recommended in C++.  Please also show the caller code.